# JList Transparency

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, transparent

I'm developing a GUI and I need to make a **JList completely transparent**, except for the selection background.

Now, I've already tried to do:

```
myList.setOpaque(false);
myScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
myScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
```

and it doesn't work.

I'm sure it's a JList matter, because it works on a JTextArea and JTable too.

I heard that there is a way to fix it with the **JList Cell Renderer** but i didn't find the documentation to do it.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user7185318 I already tried to do it in that way, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure ? If you look at the accepted answer, it shows how to do it with a cell renderer. There's also a screenshot. Perhaps you are having an old version of swing ?

Comment: @user7185318 Maybe i made a mistake with the cell renderer, i'll try

Comment: @user7185318 I fixed it, there was a stupid error in the Renderer class, thanks a lot!

Comment: I didnt answer, the answer was this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339103/transparent-jlist-in-jscrollpane-all-in-one-class

Comment: Make the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewport` also transparent